# I can`t see the option 'Create NAT64 Network' in Sharing

Tags: ios, app-store

I need to test my iOS app because it was revoked by iTunes Connect.
I'm following step by step the recommendation made ​​by App Store:

[Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1%E2%80%9D)

But when I want to select the option 'Create NAT64 Network' not shown:
[image]

Comment: I was doing from `Screen Sharing` feature, it does not work. Do this directly on the Mac

Answer (score 46, accepted):

1. You must be connected to internet by Ethernet cable, not WiFi
2. In "System Preferences", before you click on "Sharing", keep pressed and don't release the Alt key on your Mac

That way the "Create NAT64 Network" will appear[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, I don`t know that the key option is equal the key alt

Comment: "How to use a ethernet connection on a MacBook Pro 2016?"

Comment: Well, it's common on new Macs to use a Ethernet USB-C adapter, usually in corporate environments...

Comment: Is this still the case in version 10.13.6?

Answer (score 7):

I also had same problem, but below step solved my problem

Please Read this steps Carefully, it will Solve your Problem

1) Make sure your Mac is connected to the Internet, but not through Wi-Fi.

2) Launch System Preferences from your Dock, LaunchPad, or the Apple menu.

3) Press the Option key and click Sharing. Don’t release the Option key yet.

4) Select Internet Sharing in the list of sharing services.

For more info:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html